# Path element of Silverlight issue

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

Suppose I have the following XAML code. My confusions are:

1. I do not know the exact meaning of Data attribute, especially items starts with letter M/C.
2. There is no special configuration for TransformGroup (all using default settings)? Why put the TransformGroup here?

```
<Path Height="2.75" 
    Width="2.75" 
    Data="M2.75,1.375 C2.75,2.1343915 2.1343915,2.75 1.375,2.75 C0.61560845,2.75 0,2.1343915 0,1.375 C0,0.61560845 0.61560845,0 1.375,0 C2.1343915,0 2.75,0.61560845 2.75,1.375 z" 
    Fill="#FF9F9B9B" 
    Stretch="Fill" 
    Stroke="#FF000000" 
    StrokeThickness="0" 
    Canvas.Top="7" 
    x:Name="p3">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) M: move, L: line, C: curve, etc. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/BrainDump/Silverlight-and-XAML-Basics/).

2) That's just been added, no use.

I advise you to load the XAML into a XAML editor, and you'll see these in action.
Writing / understanding XAML without a WYSIWYG editor is a horror.

Comment: "I advise you to load the XAML into a XAML editor, and you'll see these in action." -- do you mean using preview function of VSTS when editing XAML in a Siverlight project or something else?

Comment: no, I mean XAMLPad http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/08/25/xamlpadx-4-0.aspx

or the offical MS Expression Blend

http://www.microsoft.com/Expression/products/Overview.aspx?key=blend

Comment: I have downloaded Exprssion Blend and seems it could only create Silverlight 1 project? But I need to develop under Siverlight 2. Any advice?

Comment: George2, Expression Blend 2.0 is out for some time, it even has an SP1. That's for SL2 development.